# Remote desktop not working anymore after reboot (Azure VM)

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012, rdp

I see a lot of different posts about this, but none seem to give me a satisfying answer.

I have a Virtual Machine running Windows server 2012, and yesterday evening I shut it down. Everything was fine, I didn't install anything on it. This morning I turned it back on, but since that time Im not able to remotely connect to it at all.

The endpoints are ok for RDP (default settings, worked before).
And it is not my local PC, since it can connect to another VM (and I checked on a different PC as well; no antivirus issue either).

I see some posts about this subject, but all seem to give solutions presented in visual studio packages and such... but we are not using this for our development.. So it's just the portal where we do stuff with... and some Powershell usage. I was hoping to do something with Powershell... but have not enough knowledge about this.
Anyone knows how to enable RDP / check status through powershell?

Comment: try a stop/start, not just a reboot. Sometimes that works (at least it does on Amazon EC2).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the connect function? Is this vm a apart of another vnetwork?  When you shut down a vm on azure you release the VIP that is external.  If you saved the rdp connection file it will not work.  That's why you use the connect function.

Comment: Rdp connexion script generated by Azure didn't reference IP adress but DNS name. The script will work even if VIP changed.

Comment: But the public port may well have changed so unless you specify a port number on RDP address you can't connect. Go to the endpoints tab on azure vm portal to see the public port to use